# VB.NET MySQL sometimes, but not always freezing whole application

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, odbc, freeze

I use

- vb.NET 2013
- Framework 2.0
- ODBC Connection from .Net Framework
- ODBC MySQL Connector 3.51

Sometimes, but not always, when i query the database the program wents to not responding and there is no error at all.

After restarting the application and run the exact same things again it all works as it should.

```
        Function GetData(ByVal xxx1 As Integer, ByVal xxx2 As DateTime, ByVal xxx3 As DateTime) As DataTable
        Dim dt As DataTable = NewDT.GetData

        Try
            SyncLock Master_Con
                Using cmd As New OdbcCommand(myCmdStr, Master_Con)
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = SQLCmd.intCmdTimeout '3
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("xxx1", OdbcType.Int).Value = xxx1
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("xxx2", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = xxx2
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("xxx3", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = xxx3
                    Using dr As OdbcDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                        If dr.HasRows Then
                            Dim rowcount As Integer = 0
                            While dr.Read()
                                dt.Rows.Add()
                                For count As Integer = 0 To (dr.FieldCount - 1)
                                    dt.Rows(rowcount).Item(count) = dr(count)
                                Next
                                rowcount = rowcount + 1
                            End While
                        End If
                    End Using
                End Using
            End SyncLock

        Catch OdbcEx As OdbcException
            MessageBox.Show("ODBC-Fehler bei Funktion 'GetData'. " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & OdbcEx.Message, "App", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Systemfehler bei Funktion 'GetData'. " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message, "App", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        End Try

        Debug.WriteLine("done.")
        Return dt

    End Function
```

My Log says something like this:

```
GetData (28.08.15 - 28.08.15)... done.
GetData2 (28.08.15)... done.
DelData... done.
GetData (28.08.15 - 28.08.15)... done.
GetData2 (28.08.15)... done.
GetData (27.08.15 - 27.08.15)... done.
GetData2 (27.08.15)... done.
GetData (26.08.15 - 26.08.15)...
```

The program just keeps not responding while running cmd.ExecuteReader.
Since i run the command in the exact same way multible times i was guessing it has something to do with the timeout or the mysql server/the connection is busy.

But since it never raises an error/odbc error and it only occures every now and then i have no clue how to solve it.

Any help would be nice!

Comment: The most likely reason for the application to get frozen is that the GUI thread is busy and the appearance of the form cannot be refreshed. In your case, I guess that some times the data is retrieved faster enough for you to notice the freezing. The best solution in these cases is relying on multithreading (i.e., running the parts taking too long in a different thread); the BackgroundWorker is quite handy for this kind of situations. Here you have some simple examples showing how to implement it: http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker-vbnet

Comment: On the other hand, it is impossible to know why in some cases your connection is slower (or even gets completely stuck). You should analyse your specific conditions carefully; and, eventually, post a question clearly describing them (not the case in this one) such that someone might propose something.

Comment: I was asking for information what to look for or analys. -> Put it in an own thread would be possible but isnt that just a workaround? The thread maybe will freeze too. Then i have to make an own timeoutloop and kill it. If its the only solution... :/

Comment: No. threads do not freeze. The freezing you see is a consequence of the GUI not doing what it is supposed to be doing. The form is being systematically updated with lots of things (e.g., the events triggered by all the controls contained in it). All the form actions (equivalently to all the ones performed by the remaining controls in the GUI) are done in the GUI thread. If the GUI thread is busy with something (e.g., a loop or getting information from a database or a file) all these actions will have to wait until it gets free again. If you put these actions in a different thread, no waiting.

Comment: See threads as 1-car-width roads (no overtaken is possible). If you don't rely on multithreading, there would be just one thread/road, used used by the GUI (which, as said, is constantly doing things which you don't realise about) and by all what you do. If you perform a given action taking too long (and don't want other ones to wait for it), you would have to create a different thread. As a general rule, any application doing some time-consuming actions (reading files, connecting to database, etc.) should rely at least on two threads/roads. One for the GUI and the other one for the rest.

Comment: And just in case this point wasn't clear still: I proposed multithreading to avoid the freezing, not avoid the slow-connection to occur. As said: it is impossible to know why your connections are some times notably slower, because you are not providing any information. You should analyse carefully all your requirements and, eventually, post a new question where your exact situation is clearly described (not the case now).

Comment: Its not slower, it doesnt respond, even after 4 hours... I put the cmd.ExecuteReader into an own thread which returns the datatable, we will see if this solve the problem. Just to be clear, the connection isnt slow or disconnecting, that should throw a timeout / odbc exeption, also the query executiontime is about some ms. I understand that it could be everything. Thank you for your constructive respond!

Comment: You are welcome. But note that a different thread would only avoid the main form to be frozen. If the connection takes so long you should analyse your exact conditions (e.g., connection to the database, information trying to be retrieved, etc.) to understand what is wrong. But your code does not provide any information (we don't even know the timeout your using, how much information you are retrieving... nothing). As said, you should be asking a new question clearly describing your exact conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was about sometimes getting a deadlock.

It now works as it should after invoking the SQLCommand execution in a its own function.

```
Private Delegate Function ExecScalarDelegate(ByVal cmd As System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand, _ 
ByRef ReturnValue As Object) As Boolean

Private Shared Function ExecScalar(ByVal cmd As System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand, _ 
ByRef ReturnValue As Object) As Boolean
    ExecScalar = False

    SyncLock cmd.Connection
        ReturnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    End SyncLock
    Return True
End Function
```